# How to determine if a BlackBerry device has Bis-B access?

Tags: blackberry

I have a BlackBerry app that performs a variety of tasks by accessing various network resources.  I have a new requirement for the app that one of these tasks has to connect to the Internet via Bis-B, and if the device isn't able to do Bis-B the app should not allow the user to perform the task in the first place.

The way to connect via Bis-B is to append this to the URL you are trying to access:

```
;deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public
```

For devices that are on Bis-B this URL suffix works and the connection is made through Bis-B.

The problem that I'm having is with devices that aren't on Bis-B.  I had assumed that if I appended the above to the URL and then attempted to connect, the attempt would fail (and I could then trap it and use that to determine that the device isn't on Bis-B).  Unfortunately, what actually happens is that the first one or two attempts *succeed*, but the second or third attempt fails with "Network could not be detected. Please try again later."  After this happens, *all* subsequent network requests fail with the same message, even the calls that *don't* use the Bis-B URL suffix.  After 10-15 minutes something seems to clear up and then all non-Bis-B network requests start working again.

So I'm naturally puzzled, and I'm looking for some way to reliable detect whether or not a device is on Bis-B.  I know that the devices themselves can tell, because the wifi icon in the upper right corner of the BB screen is bright white if the device is on Bis-B and gray when it isn't.

Comment: What OS version(s) are you supporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for some way to reliable detect whether or not a device is on Bis-B. I know that the devices themselves can tell, because the wifi icon in the upper right corner of the BB screen is bright white if the device is on Bis-B and gray when it isn't.

I have found the blackberry dots indicate whether you are on BIS or not.   They will appear next to the 3g/edge indicator if BIS is routing over the cellular network, or they will appear next to the wifi indicator if BIS is routing over wifi.

> I'm looking for some way to reliable detect whether or not a device is on Bis-B.

[CoverageInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CoverageInfo.html).getCoverageStatus() returns a bitfield, and one of the bits is CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B.  My understanding is this bit corresponds to the blackberry dots appearing in the connection status area of the home screen.

Comment: I think the BB dots are only in the newer OS versions - I don't see them at all in the pre-5.0 non-touch devices.  It turns out my code base (I inherited it) already uses CoverageInfo to determine if Bis-B is available.